# Lightweight VM For GNU/Linux to Host Windows Similar To Windows Subsystem For Linux

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, compatibility

WSL2 is a stripped down VM for GNU/Linux and as such it has a very low overhead (comparatively at least... and when Vmmem RAM usage is under control). I have been wondering if a similar, headless lightweight VM (or OCI solution) is available for GNU/Linux that can run Windows executable (and connect graphically/audibly to the host device when necessary, like WSL and OCI containers). It can be based on an official Microsoft Windows image or something more Libre/Open Source. Of course there is WINE, but as it says Wine Is Not (an) Emulator, and it lacks the cohesion and "out-of-the-box" experience of a VM

A few things I found were:

- [windows-docker-machine](https://github.com/StefanScherer/windows-docker-machine)
- [docker-wine](https://github.com/scottyhardy/docker-wine)
- [React OS (could potentially base an image on this, thought it lacks NTFS and many other features](https://reactos.org/)
- [GreenTea OS/Tofita Kernel (listed for similar reasons as React OS)](https://greenteaos.github.io/)

The first two seem to be in the early stages of development

Comment: if you could explain what kind of cohesion and "out-of-the-box" feeling you're acutely missing with WINE, maybe answers could address that specifically! I'm a bit at a loss about what you mean wiht that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry for the late reply, I suppose I mean similar in usage to WSL, without the requirement of much setup to get it working to run applications, or much knowledge of how it works, and very few decisions to make (e.g. decisions on the level of: which version of Windows, or what will your username be).

Comment: Wine offers pretty much that?

Comment: Wine requires you to pick which runtimes to install (.net, directx, etc.), the creation of a prefix, and often is just not as cohesive as WSL